# Django Rest Framework - business action specific views?

Tags: rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a basic model based view that uses a model serializer:

```
class ActionItemTextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assignee_name = serializers.CharField(source='get_assignee_name')


    class Meta:
        model = ActionItem
        fields = ('id', 'created_by', 'created_date', 'project', 'portfolio', 'name', 'description', 'parent', 'priority', 'status', 'assignee', 'assignee_name', 'wf_get_actions')
        #depth = 1


class ActionItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ActionItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActionItemTextSerializer
```

So when I go to `/actionitems/` I get a list of them and when I go to `/actionitems/5/` I will get details for an individual action item.

My action items can have specific actions associated with them - how do I go about extending all this to have the following:

`GET /actionitems/5/assign` and get model view for action item with id=5 but with additional data (I can add this via view's serializer I suppose)

`PUT /actionitems/5/assign` and trigger a view that will update the model data with PUT data and do an additional change to it based on the action key ('assign') passed to it?

Can I somehow extend the ModelViewSet so that it can return different serializer and perform different actions while PUT/POST etc based on the parameter after the /actionitems/5/? Or should I use a different approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST framework allows you to add "actions" to a ViewSet through the `@detail_route` decorator.  You can read  more about the decorator [in the documentation for ViewSets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) and it requires the use of the [built-in routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/).

In order to support multiple request methods (`PUT`/`POST`), you are going to need to pass them in through the `methods` argument to the decorator. So you would be using

```
@detail_route(methods=['post', 'put'])
```

You can then route based on the method that is being used by checking `request.method` on the `request` that is passed in.